# WPF DataBinding where the Path is recovered from the object?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have an object with several properties. Two of these are used to control the width and height of the target text box. Here is a simple example...

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type proj:SourceObject}">
    <TextBox Width="{Binding ObjWidth}" Height="{Binding ObjHeight}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I also want to bind the Text property of the TextBox. The actual property to bind against is not fixed but instead is named in a field of the SourceObject. So ideally I would want to do this...

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type proj:SourceObject}">
    <TextBox Width="{Binding ObjWidth}" Height="{Binding ObjHeight}"
             Text="{Binding Path={Binding ObjPath}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here the ObjPath is a string that returns a path that would be perfectly valid for the binding. But this does not work because you cannot use a binding against the Binding.Path. Any ideas how I can achieve the same thing?

For more context I will point out that the SourceObject is user customizable and hence the ObjPath can be updated over time and hence I cannot simply put a fixed path in the data template.

Comment: Can you move value of ObjPath to Resources? Then you can write Text="{Binding Path={DynamicResource ObjPath}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement an `IMultiValueConverter` and use this one as `BindingConverter` for your Text Property. But then you have the problem, that the value of the `Textbox` is only updated if your `ObjPath` property changes (the path itself), not the value where the path is pointing to. If that's, okay you can go with a `BindingConverter` which returns the value of your binding Path using Reflection.

```
class BindingPathToValue : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value[0] is string && value[1] != null)
        {
            // value[0] is the path
                    // value[1] is SourceObject
            // you can use reflection to get the value and return it
            return value[1].GetType().GetProperty(value.ToString()).GetValue(value[1], null).ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[], object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Have the converter in your Resources:

```
<proj:BindingPathToValue x:Key="BindingPathToValue" />
```

and use it in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type proj:SourceObject}">
    <TextBox Width="{Binding ObjWidth}" Height="{Binding ObjHeight}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource BindingPathToValue}">
                <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="ObjPath" />
                <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="." />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```